# Android Room - Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it

Tags: android, database, kotlin, android-room

```
@Entity(tableName = "gym_address_table")
data class GymAddress(@PrimaryKey val id: String, val country: Country, val unitNumber: String)

@Entity(tableName = "country_table")
data class Country(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: String,
    val isoCode: String,
    val dialCode: String,
    val name: String,
    val flagPhoto: String
)
```

So, when I try to compile this I got this error:

````
Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.

private final com.gymapp.main.data.model.country.Country country = null;```
````

I am new to Room implementation so I am not sure how to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Country is a relationship to GymAddress. You need to decide which type of relationship it has, Can a GymAddress have multiple Country.class? Potentially not so if a one-to-one relationship, you would need to annotate it accordingly with

```
@Embedded
```

Room is great, the Relationship requires additional data classes to save and retrieve etc. Which can become a pain.

Check out [Android Room Relationships](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships) to understand it further

Comment: When you ask "Can a GymAddress have multiple Country.class?" do you ask if there is an array of Countries in GymAddress or what exactly do you mean? I find it difficult to formulate the right question to tell what relation it is, because other GymAddresses could related to same country.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly the error is that Country is null, the object is null therefore it won't save as such. The main problem is that you are not passing the values, so you may need a class to pass the values with a method called Save that saves country (the object) in the database